# Use of unassigned local variable 'TargetControl'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Showing error in line 3.

Code in Below

```
if (this.Page.Master != null)
{
    Control TargetControl;
    if (this.Page.Master.FindControl(this.TargetControlID) != null)
    {
        return this.Page.Master.FindControl(this.TargetControlID);
    }
    return TargetControl;
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You're returning `TargetControl`.. but nothing is _ever_ assigned to it. So you may as well remove it entirely and just return `null`.

Comment: I don't even think this will compile, since you are returning an unassigned variable.

Comment: This is a good example of why the early-return rule still applies. The problem becomes much more apparent if you can only have one return statement.

Comment: @icemanind, "Use of unassigned local variable" is a compile-time error, I'm sure it doesn't compile :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: What early-return rule?  One entry point, one exit point was debunked years ago.

Comment: This whole function can be summed up to one line: `return Page.Master.FindControl(TargetControlID);`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I understand that it was "debunked" in that there are plenty of valid use cases for having multiple returns. However, IMHO, you should have multiple returns only with full knowledge of what you are doing and the pros/cons of doing so. Adhering to the rule in many cases is still better practice as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Somebody write an answer, and let's get on with life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to just this:

```
return Page.Master.FindControl(TargetControlID);
```

This will either return null if its not found or it'll return the control.

Answer (score 2):

> Use of unassigned local variable 'TargetControl'

Your error is because you're declaring a variable here:

```
Control TargetControl;
```

But never assigning it a value. You *must* assign values to variables before using them.

The quick solution is this:

```
Control TargetControl = null;
```

..but then, that is pretty useless in itself, you can just do this:

```
return this.Page.Master.FindControl(this.TargetControlID);
```